# definition of $G$-$C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, k-theory

I wonder what is the precise definition of a $G$-$C^*$ algebra.The document I read gave the definition of $G$-$C^*$ algebras as following:

$C^*$-algebras with a strongly continuous action by automorphisms of the group $G$.Does it mean that $G\times A\to A$ is continuous ? what is the meaning of action of automorphisms of the group?

Comment: if you do a google search for strongly continuous group action you will find the answer to te first question. Action by automorphisms means that $a\mapsto ga$ is an automorphism of C*-algbras for each $g\in G$ (each group element acts by doing an automorphism).

Comment: Is the map $G\times A \to A$ is separetely continuous?

Comment: In general strong continuity is weaker than separate continuity (cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316029/wikis-definition-of-strongly-continuous-group-action-wrong)) - it just means separately continuous in the second variable.

Comment: In general no, because the topology on $G$ doesn't have anything to do with strong continuity. Start with any strongly continuous group action, then you may retopologize $G$ and the action will still be strongly continuous. If the action is nontrivial (if there is $g,a$ such that $ga\neq a$) then if you give $G$ the discrete topology, this will not be separately continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $G$ a topological group, a $G$-$C^*$-algebra is a $C^*$-algebra $A$ with an action of $G$ on $A$ by $*$-automorphisms, such that for each $a\in A$, the map $G\to A$ given by $g\mapsto ga$ is continuous (this is so-called strong continuity).

Comment: If $G$ is a topological group,$X$ is a topoligical space,we often mention the continuous action of $G$ on $X$,.i.e. a continuous map from $G\times X \to X$.Is the above continous map denoted by strongly continous or separately continous?

Comment: It's jointly continuous:  If $g_\gamma\to g$ in $G$ and $x_\gamma\to x$ in $X$, then $g_\gamma x_\gamma\to gx$ in $X$.

Comment: Thank you so much